# Run a javascript inside control after visibled

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a control that is invisible when page loaded like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunc() {
    // do somthing
}
</script>
<a runat="server" id="aFileLink" >
</a>
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="imgThumbnail" />
```

this controle is inside of an update panel. I wanna to run myFunc() function when I set visibility of control to true. so I wrote this line after visibility of control is set to true:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "", "myFunc();" , true);
```

However, when control was shown an error is raised and say the method "myFunc" is unknown.
Why?
It seems my script block never execute because when I wrote simple "alert" function inside it, it didn't work after control showing!!!! I checked the source of page after showing control and I saw "myFunc" and "alert" functions!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just have check inside script to make sure that the code runs only when the intended element is visible

Make sure you include jquery reference

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunc() {
    if($(element).is(":visible")) {
    // do somthing
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I am talking about server side "Visible" attribute not client side or JQuery!!

Comment: Whether its sever or the client side, ultimately its on browser so setting visible true or false on the server side is same as setting display:none on the client side

Comment: Oh! you make mistake. setting visibility of control to false in asp.net server side causes that control won't be sent to the client and it won't exist in page source.

Comment: @Mojtaba thanks for the info, this is why I like stackoverflow :-)